# How to get this code working to determine if VirusTotal output is malicious is benign?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have code that is supposed to determine if the contents of a .txt file output from VirusTotal about a domain are malicious or benign. However, this code is not working. If anyone can get this code working I would greatly appreciate it! I would like to export the results to a csv file with a results column. If there are any positive results for a domain I would like to return value of True otherwise I would like to return false in the results column.

```
import csv
import json
import pprint
import sys


TOPCERTPATH = 'TopScoringCERTS_clean.txt'
BOTTOMCERTPATH = 'BottomScoringCERTS_clean.txt'
TOPCSVPATH = 'TopScoringResults.csv'
BOTTOMCSVPATH = 'BottomScoringResults.csv'
VTOUTPUTPATH = './output/'
VTOUTPUTEXT = '.txt'


pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)


# Check files from VirusTotal queries for any positive results
# Result is false unless any nonzero positive result is true
def vt_result_check(vt_result_path):
    vt_result = None
    try:
        vt_result = False
        with open(vt_result_path) as vt_result_file:
            vt_data = json.load(vt_result_file)

            # Look for any positive detected referrer samples
            try:
                for sample in (vt_data['detected_referrer_samples']):
                    if (sample['positives'] > 0):
                        vt_result = True
            except:
                pass

            # Look for any positive detected communicating samples
            try:
                for sample in (vt_data['detected_communicating_samples']):
                    if (sample['positives'] > 0):
                        vt_result = True
            except:
                pass

            # Look for any positive detected downloaded samples
            try:
                for sample in (vt_data['detected_downloaded_samples']):
                    if (sample['positives'] > 0):
                        vt_result = True
            except:
                pass

            # Look for any positive detected URLs
            try:
                for sample in (vt_data['detected_urls']):
                    if (sample['positives'] > 0):
                        vt_result = True
            except:
                pass

            # Look for a Dr. Web category of known infection source
            try:
                if (vt_data['Dr.Web category'] == "known infection source"):
                    vt_result = True
            except:
                pass

            # Look for a Forecepoint ThreatSeeker category of elevated exposure
            try:
                if (vt_data['Forcepoint ThreatSeeker category'] == "elevated exposure"):
                    vt_result = True
            except:
                pass

            # Look for a Forecepoint ThreatSeeker category of phishing and other frauds
            try:
                if (vt_data['Forcepoint ThreatSeeker category'] == "phishing and other frauds"):
                    vt_result = True
            except:
                pass

            # Look for a Forecepoint ThreatSeeker category of suspicious content
            try:
                if (vt_data['Forcepoint ThreatSeeker category'] == "suspicious content"):
                    vt_result = True
            except:
                pass

            #pp.pprint(vt_data)
    except:
        pass
    return vt_result
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Not working"? Does it throw errors? Is the output incorrect? Please elaborate.

Comment: @roganjosh Thank you for your reply! There is no output to the screen. That is what I mean by not working

Comment: You're not actually calling the function in the code you've shown so it's possible nothing inside the function actually runs. But if it is called, you've commented out the only line that prints anything so you shouldn't have any expectation for output on the screen

Comment: You should also avoid blanket `except` and only catch errors you anticipate. Currently, if you have any errors, they will be completely hidden from you because the code just ignores it and continues on its way.

Comment: @roganjosh Thanks you for your reply! After looking at the code, I can't find where the blanket except is occurring since there are many except statements. Can you help me out by telling me where the blanket exception occurs?

Comment: That is a "blanket" `except`. In other words, it will catch _every_ exception that could arise (even `KeyBoardInterrupt` if you try to abort the code). You should be specific e.g. `except KeyError` or `except TypeError` etc. Since your response to the exception is simply to `pass`, every possible error goes undetected.

Comment: @roganjosh Thank you for your response! Can you please give me an example of the proper formatting? I would greatly appreciate it!